# CS50 - PSet4 (Filter) - Blur

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I'm running  the following code

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int div = 1;

            if ( j + 1 < width - 1 && j + 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
             if ( i + 1 < height - 1 && i + 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
             if ( j + 1 < width - 1 && j + 1 > 0 && i + 1 < height - 1 && i + 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
            if ( i - 1 < height - 1 && i - 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
            if ( i - 1 < height - 1 && i - 1 > 0 && j + 1 < width - 1 && j + 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
             if ( j - 1 < width - 1 && j - 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
             else
            {
                image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
              if ( j - 1 < width - 1 && j - 1 > 0 && i + 1 < height - 1 && i + 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
             if ( j - 1 < width - 1 && j - 1 > 0 && i - 1 < height - 1 && i - 1 > 0)
            {
                div++;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
                image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = 0;
            }
            int averageR = (float)(image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / div;
            int averageG = (float)(image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / div;
            int averageB = (float)(image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / div;
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(averageR);
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(averageG);
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(averageB);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Unfortnately, everytime I try to run it in the blur part it appears this message:

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==8771==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7f7a4ec2890a (pc 0x000000427faa bp 0x7ffd07cd9170 sp 0x7ffd07cd7560 T8771)
==8771==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
    #0 0x427fa9  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x427fa9)
    #1 0x4232b1  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x4232b1)
    #2 0x7f7a4db1bb96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x402dd9  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x402dd9)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==8771==ABORTING
```

Any idea what this might be?

Comment: You should provide a minimal re-producible code snippet, so that we can check what is wrong.

Comment: you must have done some operation on an uninitialized value

Comment: Please, provide also the code that generated this error message.

Comment: @earik87 I don't know if you are asking for the code but I comment the code now. I'm really confused with this code.

Comment: @Chase can u see my code and tell me what I haven't initialized? Thank you.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni ok, I now provided the code in the answers to this post. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing out of the bounds of your `image` 2D array.

This happens in several points.

Consider your loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        
    }
}
```

`i` and `j` are indexes that can vary respectively from 0 and `height` and from 0 and `width`.

But for both these loops you access beyond this limit. For example if `j = width-1`:

```
if ( j + 1 < width - 1 && j + 1 > 0)
{
    div++;
}
else
{
    image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
    image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
    image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
}
```

The first conditional won't be true as `width-1+1 > width -1`, so you will end up in the `else` section, in which you will access

```
image[i][width].rgbtRed = 0;
```

that is out of bounds! 
And the same happens whenever `i = height-1`: rows such as `image[i + 1][j]` will access

```
image[height][j].rgbtRed = 0;
```

that is out of bounds as well.

Accessing arrays out of bounds results in **undefined behavior**, and that's what your sanitizer detects.

---

**Note**: although it is unrelated to the error you are asking for, you might also want to correct the mistake in

```
image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = 0;
```

and in similar parts all over the function. Note that only *Red* level is affected (three times!); I suppose that you intended affect also *Green* and *Blue*, instead.

---

### How to proceed

Implementing the whole function for you would be beyond the scope of this question, but I'll try to suggest how to proceed.

For each pixel, you currently

1. Count the elements that are not in the edge of the image (`div++`)
2. Set to 0 the elements that should not contribute to the average (that are actually *out of bounds* and caused your undefined behavior)
3. Sum all the values of the elements surrounding the pixel (including those you set to 0) and divide by div

**But what forces you to sum all the elements?** Just sum those which are actually useful! You already have a correct place in which to perform this sum: it's the place in which you increment `div`.

Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        int div = 1;
        int curRedSum = 0, curGReenSum = 0, curBlueSum = 0;

        if ( j + 1 < width - 1 && j + 1 > 0)
        {
            div++;
            curRedSum   += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
            curGreenSum += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
            curBlueSum  += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
        }

        if ( i + 1 < height - 1 && i + 1 > 0)
        {
            div++;
            curRedSum   += image[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
            curGreenSum += image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
            curBlueSum  += image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
        /* ... */
        float averageR = (float)(curRedSum / ( float )div );
        float averageG = (float)(curGreenSum / ( float )div );
        float averageB = (float)(curBlueSum / ( float )div );

        image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(averageR);   // Shouldn't this assignemnt be performed on a copy of the image?
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(averageG); // Shouldn't this assignemnt be performed on a copy of the image?
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(averageB);  // Shouldn't this assignemnt be performed on a copy of the image?
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** this suggestion is supposed to be just an hint. I don't guarantee this will compile and work without any further adjustment.

Comment: You mean I don't get at least one element as a freebie? Boundary scans can be tricky. Corners, sides, top and bottom pixels present special cases. Good eyes.

Comment: Thank you @Roberto Caboni. I think I understand what I did wrong but I don't know how to solve it. How can I say that else if the pixel doesnt exist don't do nothing. Can you help me in this part? And you are right I was trying to put one in red, one in green and one in blue. Thank you.

Comment: @MrPancakes you could start by looping `i` from 1 to `height-2` (instead of `[0 - height-2]` range and `j` from 1 to `width-2` (instead of `[0 - width-2]` range).

Comment: @MrPancakes I added a section containing, if not the full implementation, some hints on how to proceed. I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, @RobertoCaboni gonna try that. Thank you.

Comment: Done. I adapted with some of your tips. Thank you.